# Data representatives in EU, UK, Switzerland - are there more countries requiring this?

Tags: gdpr

The EU's GDPR requires a data representative (person or company with an address) located in the EU for everyone outside of the EU who deals with personal data of people in the EU. Practically, a non-EU company or organization has to rent a agency's service for this (typically 100+ EUR/month).

In a similar fashion, the United Kingdom requires such a data representative (person or company with an address) located in UK for everyone outside of UK who deals with personal data of people in UK.

Switzerland will update its data law (called "revDSG", Art. 14) in 2022, also then requiring a data representative (person or company with an address) located in Switzerland for outsiders dealing with Swiss people's data.

I am aware of these three countries. Is there more like this in planning announced by other countries or already installed?